# In Island of Terror, there are monsters as a result of cancer research -- was it explained how this happened?

Tags: island-of-terror

I did see the movie but recall nothing in the way of an explanation of how such monsters arose. Like nowadays, there would be nanomachines that ran wild or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only [...he was trying to create some form of living matter to counteract the cancer cells...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7jghT4P--k&t=2239s)
and [was targeting cell with radiation](https://youtu.be/w7jghT4P--k?list=PLOKOw2LY5qLFLNWK8zpP-6QXEUCiZgDKT&t=2832)

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-universe, this is yet another take on HG Well's story [The Island of Doctor Moreau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_of_Doctor_Moreau).  The method by which monsters are achieved depends on medical science of the era in which the story is retold.  In all versions, the method is merely handwaved as a vague reason for "we got monsters, now here's the story".

Comment: I disagree: the nature of the monsters, beasts turned into humans and then reverting to beasts is central to the story. the only similarity is an island and monsters.